# Which algorithmic function is faster in its growth ,O(n^2) or O(n^2*log(n)) and why?

Tags: algorithm, function, calculus

I applied random values of n  which are 1,2,4,8,16,32 and 64 to the functions (n^2) and ((n^2)*log(n)).The values of n^2 are higher than the values of ((n^2)*log(n)) but at some point the values of ((n^2)*log(n)) surpass the values of (n^2). The table of the values is:

```
      n     n^2       (n^2 *log(n))
      1     1          0
      2     4          1.2
      4     16         9.6
      8     64         57.79
      16    256        308.25
      32    1156       1541.27
      64    4096       7398.11
```

From the table above, which algorithmic function would one conclude that it has a faster growth and why?

Comment: А silly example: look at `n` and `10 + log n`. For n ≤ 11, `n < 10 + log n`. Looking at n→infinity, though, `n` is much faster.

Comment: The values are smaller for those where log(n) is < 1, which, as you seem to be using log10 here, are all the values < 10 (log2 is more usual, but does not really matter).

Comment: I understand your argument that 10+log(n) is faster than n. In this case, log n is being multiplied to n^2 and it's values are being compared to n^2. What you notice is that the values of n^2 are surpassed by the values of (n^2)*log n at some point. However, it is not consistent that the values of n^2 are continuously higher than  ((n^2)*log(n)). At what point would one choose the algoritmic function that is faster in growth than the other?

Comment: @tobias_k I'm using logarithm to base 2

Comment: Nope, definitely log base 10.

Comment: Anyway, your question (and what it's really about) is which function _grows_ faster, not which is higher for some small values, just like O(10) is larger than O(n) for small values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complexity analysis typically focuses on asymptotic behavior since we only generally care about performance when we are doing large computations (inefficient computations on small problem sizes are not the typical object of study).

Given that, behavior for small inputs is typically ignored and we say that one function is asymptotically bound from above (f = O(g)), meaning that f grows no faster than g, if that is eventually always the case.

Clearly, n^2 log(n) is eventually always greater than n^2, since log(n) eventually assumes values greater than one for any logarithm base, after which point n^2 log(n) is always greater than n^2. It is true that for values less than the logarithm base it has a smaller value, but there will only ever be a small number of such input sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If `log` is the logarithm with base 10, then `log(10)=1`, i.e. `n^2*log(n)>n^2` for `n>10`. This is true for all other logarithm bases too, i.e. `n^2*log(n,b)>n^2` for `n>b` if `log(n,b)` is the logarithm of `n` with base `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why for some small values `n^2` is faster than `n^2*logn` is that *log<sub>b</sub>(n) < 1* for all *n < b*. You seem to be using *log<sub>10</sub>*, so that point is between `8` and `16`.

```
  n  n^2  logn  n^2*logn
------------------------
  1    1  0.00     0.00
  2    4  0.30     1.20
  4   16  0.60     9.63
  8   64  0.90    57.80  ^^^ logn < 1
 16  256  1.20   308.25  vvv logn > 1
 32 1024  1.51  1541.27
 64 4096  1.81  7398.11
```

After that, `logn` is larger than one and keeps growing (although slower and slower), meaning that for all higher values, `n^2*logn` is both larger and faster-growing than `n^2`. That it is smaller for some small values of `n` is irrelevant, just like a function with constant complexity may be slower than an exponential one for some small inputs.

Answer (score 0):

What we wanna know is: will `log(n)` be bigger than 1?

If we are comparing `O(n²)` with `O(n² log(n))`, we need to know if `log(n)` is bigger or smaller than 1. As you said, I am considering `log(n)` as the logarithm in base **2**.

```
log(n) > 1   
n > 2^1
n > 2
```

After `n > 2`, `log(n) > 1`, which means that `O(n²) < O(n² log(n))` for all `n > 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can show it by limiting these two:

```
lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 / (n^2 * log(n)) = lim_{n \to \infty} 1 / log(n) = 0
```

The last step is because the `log` function is a strictly increasing function. Hence, base on the limiting result,
it means `n^2 = o(n^2 * log(n))` (little-oh) and growth of `n^2*log(n)` is faster than `n^2`.